# How to get token in Quickblox?

Tags: quickblox

I'm using Quickblox in my C# (Xamarin) app. I was unable to port Windows Phone code, so I decided you use the RESTful API.

I'm having problems with getting the token.
I followed [this tutorial](http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization) and here's my code:

```
public string Timestamp()
    {
        long ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - DateTime.Parse("01/01/1970 00:00:00").Ticks;
        ticks /= 10000000;
        return ticks.ToString();
    }

    public string GetToken()
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.quickblox.com/session.xml");

        string application_id = "2675";
        string auth_key = "rGvHTKPyJJQ8PFR";
        string timestamp = Timestamp ();
        string auth_secret = "wePb4NG74eZT3eK";

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "application_id=" + application_id;
        postData += "&auth_key=" + auth_key;
        postData += "&timestamp=" + timestamp;

        string signature = Hash (auth_secret, postData);
        postData += "&signature=" + signature;
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        httpWReq.Method = "POST";
        httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
        httpWReq.Headers ["QuickBlox-REST-API-Version"] = "0.1.0";

        using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

        string responseString = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd ();
        return responseString;
    }
```

In the result I'm getting an exception "422: Unprocessable Entity" when trying to receive `httpWReq.GetResponse()`

Comment: can you please share your hash function? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add **nonce** parameter.

Also you should use it when generating signature